# How can I access a value of a Kivy class from another Screen class?

Tags: python, kivy, kivy-language

I need to access the value of `LoginScreen().filename` declared in Line 34, from `<ShareScreen>` in the Kivy code. In other words, `filename` has the path to an image and I need to display that image in `ShareScreen` screen. Here's what I tried:

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import Screen, ScreenManager


Builder.load_string("""
<LoginScreen>:
    GridLayout:
        cols: 1
        Button:
            text: 'Next Screen'
            size_hint_y: None
            height: '48dp'
            on_press: root.next_screen()

<ShareScreen>:
    GridLayout:
        cols: 1
        Image:
            source: app.root.login_screen.filename

<RootWidget>:
    LoginScreen:
        id: login_screen
        name: "login_screen"
    ShareScreen:
        id: share_screen
        name: "share_screen"
""")

class LoginScreen(Screen):

    def next_screen(self):
        self.filename = 'photo.png'
        self.manager.current = "share_screen"

class ShareScreen(Screen):
    pass


class RootWidget(ScreenManager):
    pass

class MainApp(App):
    def build(self):
        return RootWidget()


MainApp().run()
```

That code gives me this error:

```
 >>   15:            source: app.root.login_screen.filename
      16:
      17:<RootWidget>:
 ...
 AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'login_screen'
```

How can I get the path of the image (i.e. the `filename` value) to display it in `ShareScreen`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can change the `ShareScreen` rule to:

```
<ShareScreen>:
    GridLayout:
        cols: 1
        Image:
            id: img
```

which remove the offending `source` and adds an `id` to the `Image`. Then you can change the `next_screen` method to:

```
class LoginScreen(Screen):

    def next_screen(self):
        self.manager.current = "share_screen"
        self.manager.current_screen.ids.img.source = 'photo.png'
```

Which sets the source of the `Image`.

Comment: That works. Just for the records, isn't there really a way to access a class from another class (i.e. the LoginScreen class from the ShareScreen class)?

Comment: From the `ShareScreen` class, you can access the `LoginScreen` class just by using something like `LoginScreen.some_login_screen_attribute`. But usually, you want to access an instance of `LoginScreen`, not the the class. See the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3.6/tutorial/classes.html#class-objects). You can think of the `LoginScreen` class as a recipe (like a cake recipe) for building an instance of `LoginScreen` (like baking a cake). If you want to taste the cake, you want to access the cake, not the recipe.